# What is the difference between PaginatedQueryList and QueryResultPage in DynamoDB?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am currently working with DynamoDB with Java and using `DynamoDBMapper`. I saw that when we use `DynamoDBQueryExpression` we can use either `PaginatedQueryList` or `QueryResultPage`. If we are using any of them below are the methods we have to use,

```
query method - returns a [PaginatedQueryList][1]
queryPage method - returns a [QueryResultPage][1]
```

`PaginatedQueryList` says it will first load 1MB of data and if we iterate over then it will load next page if needed and also this is paginated. But what about `QueryResultPage`? It says it is loading 1MB of data. But what about if we iterate it? Will it load the second page or just only give us 1MB of data? I couldn't find anything about that? And also `QueryResultPage` gives us the `LastEvaluatedKey` but `PaginatedQueryList` not. So is there a way to get the `LastEvaluatedKey` in `PaginatedQueryList` or else if we need to get that key do we have to always use the `QueryResultPage`?

And also instead of the following code,

```
PaginatedQueryList<Data> data = dynamoDBMapper.query(Data.class, queryExpression);
```

If we use the following,

```
List<Data> data = dynamoDBMapper.query(Data.class, queryExpression);
data.size();
```

Will it load the all data found in DB? What if I use `stream()` instead of `data.size()` will it load all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

- `QueryResultPage` won't load any additional data lazily, only `PaginatedQueryList` does that.
- `PaginatedQueryList` abstracts away the pagination for you, that's why it doesn't expose the key. If you need the key, you'll need to use `queryPage` with `QueryResultPage`. In case you need more than just the first page, you'll have to request the other pages on your own.
- `.size()` will load all data into memory, as you need to have the data, to count them.
- `.stream()` might load all data into memory, depending on what you do with the stream. If you say `.stream().limit(1)` then no more pages will be loaded. But if you say `.stream().count()` then **all pages** will be loaded.

---

Looking at the documentation of those 2, `PaginatedQueryList` seems to be an object, which tries to abstract away from you the fact, that underneath the results are paginated.

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/PaginatedQueryList.html (emphasis mine):

> [...] Paginated results are **loaded on demand** when the user executes an operation that requires them. **Some operations**, such as size(), must **fetch the entire list**, but results are **lazily fetched page by page when possible**.

So, if you basically don't want to deal with paginations, use the `query` method. But keep in mind, that you application will ultimately still need to page through the results, if you want to return all of them (or know their size)

On the other hand, `QueryResultPage` is closer to the DynamoDB API. You are dealing with a page, and you can use [`getLastEvaluatedKey()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/QueryResultPage.html#getLastEvaluatedKey--) to get the parameter to be used for the next [`setExclusiveStartKey`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBQueryExpression.html#setExclusiveStartKey-java.util.Map-) (on your [`DynamoDBQueryExpression`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBQueryExpression.html))

**In summary:**

- `query` is more user friendly, as it hides the explicit pagination, but if your result contains many pages, your code might get slower without you noticing it at first, because those pages are loaded lazily.
- `queryPage` is more explicit about the intent. You must load every page manually and therefore think if you really need all the data, or if you don't want to further offload pagination to your client, for instance.

You can read a similar description when reading the official documentation of `queryPage` at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Methods.html#DynamoDBMapper.Methods.queryPage (emphasis mine):

> Queries a table or secondary index and returns a single page of matching results. As with the query method, you must specify a partition key value and a query filter that is applied on the sort key attribute. **However, queryPage returns only the first "page"** of data, that is, the amount of data that fits in 1 MB

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. And also thank you for putting your time to answer this question. About `stream()` what if I do `stream().map(do something with the data).collect(Collectors.toList());`. Will it load all the data?

Comment: as I wrote in the answer - if you perform a stream operation on all items of the stream, all the pages should be loaded transparently for you. This means, that you need to explicitly limit the stream to the initial page(s) if you don't want the others to be loaded `stream().map(...).collect(...)` doesn't limit the items

Comment: OK I got it. Thank you very much.